# Highlight data based on a condition using Python Pandas and write it back to same .xls file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a sample dataset, I want to

1. Highlight the cell and add a comment column with comment "Null/Blank in 'Item' column"
2. Highlight the cell and a add a comment column with comment "presence of '_' in 'Store' Column"
3. Highlight the cell and add a comment column with comment "Keyword 'Pen' should not tagged to Fruits category"

Input Dataset

| Store | Item | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Store A |  | Fruits |
| Store A | Apple_ | Fruits |
| Store A | Orange | Fruits |
| Store A | Banana | Fruits |
| Store_B | Books | Stationary |
| Store B | Pen | Fruits |
| Store B | Pencil | Fruits |
| Store B | Glue | Stationary |
| Store B | Eraser | Stationary |
| Store C | Frozen | Movies |
| Store_C | Titanic | Movies |
| Store C | Iron_Man | Movies |
| Store C |  | Movies |

[Input Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFUBs.png)

Output Dataset

[Output Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyVTy.png)

Thanks

Comment: Please add the data in tabular form as well, so that it's easier for people to work with. Thanks!

Comment: If a same row need to be highlighted twice?

Comment: Yes, highlight that particular cell in yellow if the condition matches. if the same row has 2 conditional match, highlight both those cells on that row. Attached output dataset image for reference

Comment: Do you update your "Output Dataset"? How to fill the column "Highlight Comments"?

Comment: Yes , update dataset and add a comment column and fill in the highlight comments

Answer (score 0):

Input data:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""Store;Item;Category\nStore A;;Fruits\nStore A;Apple_;Fruits\nStore A;Orange;Fruits\nStore A;Banana;Fruits\nStore_B;Books;Stationary\nStore B;Pen;Fruits\nStore_B;Pencil;Fruits\nStore B;Glue;Stationary\nStore B;Eraser;Stationary\nStore C;Frozen;Movies\nStore_C;Titanic;Movies\nStore C;Iron_Man;Movies\nStore C;;Movies"""), sep=";")
```

I slightly modified your data to be able highlight a row twice:

```
>>> df
      Store      Item    Category
0   Store A       NaN      Fruits
1   Store A    Apple_      Fruits
2   Store A    Orange      Fruits
3   Store A    Banana      Fruits
4   Store_B     Books  Stationary
5   Store B       Pen      Fruits
6   Store_B    Pencil      Fruits
7   Store B      Glue  Stationary
8   Store B    Eraser  Stationary
9   Store C    Frozen      Movies
10  Store_C   Titanic      Movies
11  Store C  Iron_Man      Movies
12  Store C       NaN      Movies
```

Try to detect errors:

```
comments = {"m1": "Null/Blank in Item column",
            "m2": "Presence of '_' in Store column",
            "m3": "Keyword 'Pen' should not tagged to Fruits category"}

# Conditions
m1 = (df["Item"].str.len() == 0) | (df["Item"].isna())
m2 = df["Store"].str.contains("_")
m3 = (df["Item"].str.startswith("Pen")) & (df["Category"].str.match("Fruits"))

dfm = pd.DataFrame({"m1": m1, "m2": m2, "m3": m3}, index=df.index)

df["Highlight Comments"] = dfm.mul(pd.DataFrame(comments, index=df.index)) \
                              .apply(lambda c: ', '.join(filter(bool, c)), axis="columns")
```

```
>>> df["Highlight Comments"]
0                                                               Null/Blank in Item column
1
2
3
4                                                         Presence of '_' in Store column
5                                      Keyword 'Pen' should not tagged to Fruits category
6     Presence of '_' in Store column, Keyword 'Pen' should not tagged to Fruits category
7
8
9
10                                                        Presence of '_' in Store column
11
12                                                              Null/Blank in Item column
Name: Highlight Comments, dtype: object
```

Export to excel and set style to cells:

```
import openpyxl as xl

with pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx", engine="openpyxl") as writer:
  df.to_excel(writer, index=False)
  ws = writer.book.active

  # convert indexes to excel cell coordinates (so ugly!)
  dfm.columns = [chr(ord('A') + i) for i, _ in enumerate(dfm.columns)]
  dfm.index = map(str, dfm.index + 2)

  highlight = xl.styles.PatternFill(fill_type="solid", start_color="ffff00", end_color="ffff00")
  for cell in dfm.unstack()[dfm.unstack()].index.map(''.join):
    ws[cell].fill = highlight
```

Comment: Have you tested the solution to your question?